# Can't Stretch Image and Override Aspect Ratio with Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer

I have the following HTML to display an image:

```
<img src="img_locations/location1.jpg" height="200px" width="300px">
```

The aspect ratio I've set above is 3:2.  The image itself has an aspect ratio of 4:3.  The above stretches the image and displays the correct pixels in Chrome / Firefox.  In IE10 / IE9,  the browser takes into account the height(200px), but decreases the width so that the original 4:3 aspect ratio is preserved.

How do I overwrite this rendering in Internet Explorer and display the image in a 3:2 aspect ratio?

Comment: Can you provide a http://jsbin.com/ or http://jsfiddle.net/ test case?

Comment: Can't reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/DtL2a/ IE10 respects height/width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use CSS. Nowadays specifying width and height as HTML attributes is very bad practice. You should do something like this:

```
img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
```